# Where can I check spell hunger for my spells?

Tags: dungeon-crawl-stone-soup

Where, in game, can I check how much hunger each of my spells will cost me?

I know I can check my morgue file by dumping with # but that's tedious.

(Note that this applies to versions prior to 0.26.0; as of 0.26.0, food and hunger have been removed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to check spell hunger for the spells you have memorized is to press `z`.

Then press `?` to open your list of spells.

Then press `!` or `I` to toggle spell view instead of spell casting.

This will show the spell hunger for all the spells you have memorized.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to check the Hunger requirements for your spells. I play tiles, so ASCII may not have *all* of the same features.

The best way to get all of the information about a spell you can cast, or a spell you can learn, is looking at the spell in a spellbook.

The following images were captured playing online with tiles.

This can be accomplished by pressing **`i` (Inventory)** -> pressing the key for the book you wish to read (here you can see that is **`c`**)

[image: DCSS inventory]

-> pressing the key for the spell you wish to get information for (here I am looking at Mephitic Cloud, which is **`f`**).

[image]

This will bring up an information box which includes a Hunger rating in the form `.......` to `#######`, with the `#` character representing increasing Hunger used to cast.

[image]

Playing offline with tiles, there is also hotbar of memorized spells. Hovering over these with a mouse will provide similar information.

Comment: Okay, there are some problems with your suggestions. The first method requires me to have the book the spell came in, which can be a non-starter if I threw the book away or got it as a gift from Vehumet.  The second method leaves the line for spell hunger chopped off the bottom of the window for some spells.

Comment: @Fambida It's been a while since I've sat down and played dcss, you're very right about not needing the books once you've learned all you can from them. As for the second... sure, I'm sure you're correct. In recent memory I haven't had this happen to me but as I stated, I play tiles so usually I check my hunger on the hotbar. Thanks for pointing those out.